# Parse request line of http header

Tags: java, parsing, http, http-headers

Is there anything inbuilt in `java.net` to parse the request line on a http request?

For example:

```
CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
```

In this case I want to parse the `host` and `port`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've don it myself using

```
String request = "CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.1";
String authority = request.split(" ")[0];
String[] tokens = request.split(":");
String host = tokens[0];
int port = (tokens.length == 2)? Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) : 443;
InetSocketAddress address = InetSocketAddress(host, port);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getHost() or getPort() or getDefaultPort() methods of java.net.URL class.

For further information you can check [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPort%28%29)

Comment: Thanks. What exactly is passed to the constructor? `new URL("CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.1")`??

Comment: I am not sure of it as i never tried this way but I don't think this would create any problems. you can do it this way also if you only want host name and port new URL("google.com:443") You can refer to oracle docs for more implementation information [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html](here).